# How notify that form that executed a thread in other class?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two forms called **frm1** and **frm2**:

```
public partial class frm1 : Form

    {
        private WebMethods wm;

        public frm1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wm = new WebMethods();
            wm.test();
        }
    }
```

---

```
public partial class frm2 : Form
{
    private WebMethods wm;


    public frm2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wm = new WebMethods();
        wm.test();
    }
}
```

now I have a class called **WebMethods** :

```
class WebMethods
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;


    public void stop(){
        backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
    }


    public void test()
    {
        if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy != true)
        {
            this.backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_PostRequest);
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_PostRequestComplet  ed);
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }


    private void _PostRequest(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }


    private void _PostRequestCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

now I want when **backgroundworker** thread finished and **_PostRequestCompleted** event executed, it notify that form that executed **test()** method.

for example if **frm1** executed **test()** method at end **_PostRequestCompleted()** method notify **frm1** that thread was finished. for example **_PostRequestCompleted** executes a method in **frm1** after finishing thread.

but I dont know how do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an `event` in `WebMethods` class and register it in your form classes.

```
class WebMethods
{
    public event EventHandler PostRequestCompletedEvent;

    private void _PostRequestCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        if (PostRequestCompletedEvent != null)
        {
           PostRequestCompletedEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Now register this event in your form classes.

```
public partial class frm1 : Form
{
    private WebMethods wm;

    public frm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wm = new WebMethods();
        wm.PostRequestCompletedEvent += wm_PostRequestCompletedEvent;
        wm.test();
    }

    void wm_PostRequestCompletedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // notify frm1 that thread was finished 
    }
}

public partial class frm2 : Form
{
    private WebMethods wm;
    public frm2()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       wm = new WebMethods();
       wm.PostRequestCompletedEvent += wm_PostRequestCompletedEvent;
       wm.test();
    }

    void wm_PostRequestCompletedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // notify frm2 that thread was finished
    }
}
```